# How to invoke smth after knockoutjs template will be rendered

Tags: knockout.js, decorator, html-rendering, knockout-templating

On the page I have only one script, in the head (it is like some advertisement). And in content client have a knockoutjs temlating, and they have filter select.

I need to invoke my stuff after select filtering.
When user click to filter smth, and before content will be visible, I need to invoke some stuff (in the same thread).

How I can do this ? Have you any idea ?

P.S. So as you understand I do not have possibility to change basic template logic, which is sent from server, I can to use smth in the head (I have script there).

Answer (score 1):

Use `afterRender` property in `template` binding

> Note 4: Using “afterRender”, “afterAdd”, and “beforeRemove”

[**Documentation - template**](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html)

**Excample:**

```
<div data-bind='template: { name: "personTemplate",
                            data: myData,
                            afterRender: myPostProcessingLogic }'> </div>
```

Comment: But i have not template name. The data-binds looks like so:
data-bind="template: {name:quoteTemplate()}". Also each element will be replaced with another one, after each filter call. So I think this attribute will be the same as in default.